# How to correctly select date field using libpqxx?

Tags: c++, postgresql, libpqxx

I am trying to select date field from PostgreSQL database using libpqxx and C++.

I would use this code, but I don't know if it is legal. I have searched in the documentation but I haven't any documented way.

```
using time_point = std::chrono::steady_clock::time_point;

pqxx::work txn(c);
auto&& rst = txn.exec("SELECT date FROM table");

for(auto&& row : rst)
  time_point date = row[0].as<time_point>();
```

Is this okey please? Do you know any better alternative?

I would like the same with date time and time field. Is there any difference please?

Thank you.

--

the documentation for `field` type: https://libpqxx.readthedocs.io/en/6.4/a01063.html#a3a55f6b44040b68e70382d9db7dea457

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer on [Github](https://github.com/jtv/libpqxx/issues/206) by JadeMatrix:

`field.as<>()` will work with any type for which a specialization of `pqxx::string_traits<>` exists. libpqxx comes with support for `std::string`, builtin numerics (int, etc.), and maybe a few others I don't remember.
Support for `std::chrono::` types are missing by default, unfortunately. You can implement your own, but be warned that they will only work for `TIMESTAMP WITHOUT TIME ZONE`, `DATE`, `TIME WITHOUT TIME ZONE`, and `INTERVAL`. To correctly support … `WITH TIME ZONE` you will need Howard Hinnant's date library, which is what I use (there is talk of adding it to the standard library).
If you want, I can share my code, which relies on date functionality for parsing Postgres date/time strings (ISO 8601 format).

Comment: Hello @přemysl-Šťastný, please add your code for parsing date and time with time zone support. Thank you.

Comment: Sorry, I don't have time for this just now. Try to contact author on Github.